# User defined fields model in django

Tags: django

I want to allow my users to define custom properties.

They are managing apartments so each customer manages the apartments in different way. 
I want to allow them to define some custom properties for they apartments.

```
class Unit(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    max_occupants = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    floor = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    rooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    is_disabled_access = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    balcony_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    recomended_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

I want them to be able additional fields to this model. 
For example - is_breaker is_fuse Number_of

Since I cant predict what data they will require.

how can I do it?

Comment: For each models modification you need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` for your changes to take effect in the database, this means that you can not do what you want here with relational databases. Instead, you might need to take a look at NoSQL databases and take advantage of what they provide in terms of database schema flexibility.

Comment: for the reasons @ettanany points out, this won't work. However I wouldn't solve it with NoSQL (assuming the rest of your data is pretty relational). There are a number of tagging applications that will let people do arbitrary tags. Or, if you want to define them, use a many-to-many field to an 'attributes' model.

Comment: If you use postgres you can store extra fields in JSONField. Or you can create user-unit-field-value property table and store it there. Depends on what you are planning to do with those fields later (just store or store and query)

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend the following solution:

1.Create a "property" Model:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.property
```

2.To your Unit model, add a ManytoMany field with property model:

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    (...)
    properties = models.ManyToManyField(Property)
```

3.Add an inline in your admin to view the different Properties:

```
class Unit(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('__all__')
    inlines = ('properties')
```

Comment: sorry, copied the code from a project, fixed it now :)

Comment: Thank you. However then how I can use it . Can I sort, filter or search by those properties. Can you post some snippets or links to give general idea.