# django user defined fields and answer model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Similar to this: [User defined fields model in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072800/user-defined-fields-model-in-django)

I am creating a COVID Prescreening system for a school project. Event creators will be able to create forms, which consist of basic questions such as temperature, contact with covid in the last 14 days, etc. as well as provide custom questions for the attendee to answer which I cannot predict.

For example, the event creator could ask 2 questions:

- How are you feeling today?
- Have you been to a party in the last week?

And every attendee for that event would have to fill out these 2 questions in addition to the standard questions.
The model for this is:

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    ''' model for an event '''
    creator = models.ForeignKey("Account", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter a title for this event")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    custom_questions = models.ManyToManyField(CustomQuestion)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} {self.uuid}'
```

Each custom question is essentially a key/value model:

```py
class CustomQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    response = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

The user will fill out the COVID Form, which will create an object as such:

```py
class CovidScreenData(models.Model):
    custom_responses = models.ManyToManyField(CustomQuestion)
    temperature = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=98.6)
    contact_with_covid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This data is embedded in the larger response, which ties everything together

```py
class Response(models.Model):
    ''' model for a completed covid screen '''
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    details = models.ForeignKey('CovidScreenData', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.account.user.username}\'s Response ({self.event.title})'
```

When the attendee is filling out the form, I want them to be given the `custom_questions` for the event they are filling out.

My idea is that when they are presented with the form, each question in `custom_questions` will be looped through and displayed. When the user submits, their response, as well as the original question, are saved in the `custom_responses` variable.

**What is the correct organization to do this?** *I am asking this rather than how do I display the questions to the user and save their responses in the model.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the response correspond to the question I think you can not use ManytoMany field on this part

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    custom_questions = models.ManyToManyField(CustomQuestion)
    ...
```

you should use ManytoOne for Event relationship with CustomQuestion (adding foreign key to Event on CustomQuestion). It's because you store the answer on the same row with the question so other event should not use the same row of CustomQuestion(containing question and answer).

also you can't store a ManytoMany in the CovidScreenData about the custom_response that actually contains CustomQuestion because the reason on my first explanation.

If you want to get and store the answer just go through the *Response* item, then get the *Event* item, and then get pairs of question-answer using foreign key on *CustomQuestion* join with the *Event* item.